# How to get a long term access token

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

Sience Facebook canceled offline_access scope,The access token I get can only available for 2 days.I read their blog,and tried to refresh token every hour.But every time the token I get is just the same as I sent to.and it expires.

It is strange that IM Plus(http://plus.im/)Never need to refresh token(as long as I registed and add Facebook connect to it,about one month)I wonder how did they do that.I discovered they are still using 'offline_access' scope. Here is their URL to get access token

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?api_key=119600778096160&app_id=119600778096160&client_id=119600778096160&display=touch&domain=plus.im&locale=en_US&origin=2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D6%23cb%3Df3d1b1d90c%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fplus.im%252Ff232f2ca44%26domain%3Dplus.im%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df336857b2c&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=read_stream%2C%20publish_stream%2C%20xmpp_login%2C%20read_mailbox%2C%20offline_access&sdk=joey

So,How to get a long term access token just like they do?

Thanks.